# How to expect some messages and ignore others with akka.net testkit?

Tags: testing, akka.net

I have a test for an actor that might respond with some unexpected messages but eventually it must respond with a particular known message. 
So in essence I want an assertion that will within in some timespan ignore other messages but expect a known message, like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Integration")]
    public async Task Should_fetch_fund_shareclass_and_details_from_test_service()
    {

        var testIsins = new HashSet<string> {"isin1", "isin2", "isin3"};

        var props = Props.Create(() => new DataFetchSupervisor());

        var actor = Sys.ActorOf(props, "fetchSupervisor");
        Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
        {
            actor.Tell(new StartDataFetch(testIsins));

            //ignore unexpected messages here

             var fetchComplteMsg = ExpectMsg<DataFetchComplete>();

        });
    }
```

So now this will fail because I get some other messages before DataFetchComplete message.

As always, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Akka.TestKit](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.html) class has a number of different versions of `ExcpectMsg` or equivalent checkers. The one you're looking for is probably a [FishForMessage](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.html#Akka_TestKit_TestKitBase_FishForMessage_System_Predicate_System_Object__System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_String_). It takes a predicate and will ignore all incoming messages as long as they will fail to pass predicate's condition. Once a passing message is found this check will complete and your code may be continued.

Comment: Ach so, didn't know about that function. That's a really nifty one too. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [TestKit.IgnoreMessages](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.TestKit.TestKitBase.html#Akka_TestKit_TestKitBase_IgnoreMessages_System_Func_System_Object_System_Boolean__) method, which will accept a delegate function specifying which types of messages you wish to ignore while waiting for your target message.